# Query sailsjs blueprint endpoints by id array using request

Tags: rest, sails.js, requestjs

I'm using the [request](https://github.com/request/request) library to make calls from one sails app to another one which exposes the default blueprint endpoints. It works fine when I query by non-id fields, but I need to run some queries by passing id arrays. The problem is that the moment you provide an id, only the first id is considered, effectively not allowing this kind of query.

Is there a way to get around this? I could switch over to another attribute if all else fails but I need to know if there is a proper way around this.

Here's how I'm querying:

```
var idArr = [];//array of ids
var queryParams = { id: idArr };
var options: {
    //headers, method and url here
    json: queryParams
};
request(options, function(err, response, body){
    if (err) return next(err);
    return next(null, body);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sails blueprint APIs allow you to use the same waterline query langauge that you would otherwise use in code.

You can directly pass the array of id's in the get call to receive the objects as follows

```
GET /city?where={"id":[1, 2]}
```

Refer [here](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/find-where) for more.

Have fun!

Comment: For some reason this wasn't working for me the last time. Repeated the same mistake and finally figured I wasn't using double quotes. This is a load off my head. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I switched to a hacky solution to get moving.

For all models that needed querying by id arrays, I added a secondary attribute to the model. Let's call it `code`. Then, in `afterCreate()`, I updated `code` and set it equal to the `id`. This incurs an additional database call, but it's fine since it's called just once - when the object is created.

Here's the code.

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        code: {
            type: 'string'//the secondary attribute
        },
        // other attributes
    },
    afterCreate: function (newObj, next) {
        Model.update({ id: newObj.id }, { code: newObj.id }, next);
    }
}
```

Note that `newObj` isn't a Model object as even I was led to believe. So we cannot simply update its `code` and call `newObj.save()`.

After this, in the queries having `id` arrays, substituting `id` with `code` makes them work as expected!